# Tests randomly failing in IEDriverServer

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am currently facing a bit of a problem.

In chrome and firefox, the tests run perfectly however during the test run of IE, sometimes they are failing to pick certain elements.

(Chrome and firefox tests all pass and in IE sometimes one or more tests fail. However sometimes they all pass. It seems to be a bit random.)

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Code I am using to call the IEDriver:

```
var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.LibraryExtractionPath = "Path to extraction path";
service.Port = 1089;

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

InternetExplorerDriver("Path",options);
return ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options);
```

Using IEDriver 3.5.1.0 on IE11

Answer (score 0):

Flaky tests are a big thing in the Selenium based tests. Simply put - there are just too many factors that may affect your execution. My experience with IE has taught me that browsers actually build the DOM and render the content with different speed. Which means your WebElements are enabled and you can interact with them in different time ranges (which may vary greatly), especially for rich animations.

[image]

As [you can see](https://blog.en.uptodown.com/browser-comparison-chrome-firefox-explorer-opera/) IE is not a top performer when it comes to loading speed, memory usage, and performance in tests on general page rendering operations and calculations with HTML5.

What could help you:

- add custom JS condition before calling ExplicitWaits, like so (trying to remember the code I was using in my framework back then):

  ```
   // need to wait for Javascript to load
   ((IJavascriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString().Equals("complete");
   // need to wait for jQuery to load
   ((IJavascriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return (window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0);");
  ```
- be sure to give enough time (Waits) before interacting with the page elements.

Comment: @ekonstadinov First of all, thank you for your thorough reply. However the page elements (example: text boxes, buttons) are all being rendered. The problem seems to be that the code isn't able to find the elements that I am looking for, which seems to happen randomly so I don't think its a JS problem. Do you have an idea of what else it can be? (I give them 3 seconds of wait before interacting and then another 30 seconds to find the element)

Comment: I would say that if it is able to find the elements on IE even once - it is not a selector issue. However I've faced similar edge cases w/ XPath and Firefox. So you can try with different locator e.g. if current one is CSS, try XPath and vise versa. In general driver-browser sync problems are not that rare and those require detailed debugging. One more thing - is the FE using some complex framework like angular? If yes - u'll need some more complicated porting to handle its events too.